# Connector stuck in review for 7 months with no replies

Tags: office365connectors

I updated my connector in February and since then it's stuck in a review state. I've tried emailing teamssubsupport@microsoft.com by got no answer. Does anybody know a contact email I could write to ?

Comment: Could you please share your Connector id?

Comment: My Connector id is afe63f50-aadc-4139-82dc-ba8da6270be9

Comment: This Connector is approved. Also, here is correct alias - teamsubm@microsoft.com